# how to convert .HTML file to .DOC file...?

Tags: java

i am working in JSF Application and in this application using some code i have create a HTML file that is store in my server and now i want to convert that HTML file in to .DOC file ..... so please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution is i have Download a

```
officetools.OfficeFile;
```

this jar file and after write some code that can easy get from the net...

Answer (score 0):

There are tools that convert HTML to PDF: [Convert an HTML file to a PDF with their pictures and styles using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4449989/convert-an-html-to-a-pdf-with-their-pictures-and-styles-by-using-java)

Then use: http://pdf-to-doc.software.informer.com/

Comment: thank's for your response but now i did it using  import officetools.OfficeFile jar......

Answer (score 0):

You could strip it of script and comments etc, then load it into Word and save it as .doc.

Comment: thank's for your response but now i did it using  import officetools.OfficeFile jar......

Answer (score 0):

You can convert HTML to XML (using XSLT) and load it into Word afterwards. I did it while converting HTML page with tables to XML with XSLT file attached and it worked just fine.

Comment: thank's for your response but now i did it using  import officetools.OfficeFile jar......