# Convert an HTML file to a PDF with their pictures and styles using Java

Tags: java, pdf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Converting HTML Files to PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/633780/converting-html-files-to-pdf)

I want to convert an HTML file to PDF by using Java. I've searched stackoverflow and other sites. I am suprised. Because I couldn't find any easy way.

Could you help me with to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think, because there is no easy way to do it. You can consider HTML+CSS -> xhtml -> XSLT->XSL-FO->PDF. Too complicated, really.

Comment: Does anyone ever search existing answers?  This question has been asked over and over again.

Answer (score 0):

http://pd4ml.com/index.htm

http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-04-2006/jw-0410-html.html

http://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CDAQFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.oooforum.org%2Fforum%2Fviewtopic.phtml%3Ft%3D53745&ei=77gITcewF8bGswbl7aCTAw&usg=AFQjCNGYBzcnQVT3kShaz0ls7MSHYJImJQ&sig2=dZlfImCEsW5G5b3Oo4TvyA

more googleing?

Comment: thanks.. but did you really check these links? As I said before I've already checked from google. OO doesn't support css. So in the second link includes a huge workflow (first you should change html to xhtml and you should prepare a huge architecture etc.) And pdml is not free? There is no easy way???

Answer (score 0):

If there is no Java library to do this, I suggest finding a command-line tool that does the job, and invoking it from Java using Runtime.exec(). Not ideal though.

Answer (score -3):

here is the sample to do that

```
                   import officetools.OfficeFile; // this is my tools package
        ...
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File("test.html"));
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("test.pdf"));

        // suppose OpenOffice.org runs on localhost, port 8100
        OfficeFile f = new OfficeFile(fis,"localhost","8100", true); 

        f.convert(fos,"pdf");
        ...
```

Comment: and where do we find this tool package ?

Comment: Just doing a copy/paste from a link such as http://www.daniweb.com/forums/thread130906.html isn't of much help

Comment: @Valentin: seems to be a part of `officetools.jar`, which is unfortunately not free, but can be obtained from [this site](http://www.dancrintea.ro/doc-to-pdf/).

Comment: it is a JAR file u can find it in the net.http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/239156-49-officefile-download